# Validate comma separated decimal values reading char by char

Tags: python, char, python-2.5

I have a String which contains a Currency Value.
I have to read character by character from string and function must return `result = 0` for all values of `val`.

Ex: `string = "You Score is MX var."`
Where `var`  can have any of these values

```
[14 , 14.98 , 114 , 114.98 , 1116 , 1,116 , 1116.78 , 1,116.18 , 11,12,123 , 1,12,123.89 ... and so on...]
```

**MY CODE**

```
def evaluate():
    result , count = 0 , 0
    dot , comma = False , False
    while (index_of_String < Len_of_string):
        ch = string[index_of_String]        
        if (ch == '.'):
            if (dot == True):
                break ;                
            dot = True            
        elif (ch == ','):
            if (dot == True):
                break            
            comma = True             
        elif not (ch >= '0' and ch <= '9'):
            if not (ch == ' ' or ch == ','):                
                result = -1            
            break
        else:
            if (dot == False):
                count += 1
        print ("Char %c" % ch)
        index_of_String += 1        

    print ("count of numeric digits %d" % count)
    if (result == 0):
        if dot == False:
            result = -1
        if comma == False:
            if (count > 3):
                result = -1

    return (result, index_of_String)
```

> **Required Output**

```
string = "You Score is MX 14."
result = 0

string = "You Score is MX 14.89."
result = 0

string = "You Score is MX 1114.89."
result = 0

string = "You Score is MX 1,114.89."
result = 0  

string = "You Score is MX 11,,,14.89."
result = -1 (fail)

string = "You Score is MX 11.14.89."
result = -1 (fail)

string = "You Score is MX 1,114.89."
result = 0  

string = "You Score is MX 1,14.89."
result = -1 (fail)

string = "You Score is MX 1,11,114.89."
result = 0
```

What modification(s) do I need to make my code works for all these cases.
Any Help in modifying??

Comment: @Schoolboy replace `rIndex` with  `index_of_String`.

Comment: 1-is reading character by character a requirement? 2-Does `1,116.18` mean `1116.18` or the two values `1` and `116.8`? 3-Can we assume there is only one numeric value in the string?

Comment: Can you explain your example? It is highly confusing!

Comment: @elyase yes...`1,116.18` is `1116.18` 
Sorry if it seems confusing but my question is I have a string which contain one of those numeric values which may be non decimal, decimal, decimal with comma, non-decimal with comma. And i have to verify weather those are correct or not. if correct `return 0` else `return -1`

Comment: @elyase 
As You asked For 
First: it must be read char by char 
Second : 1116.18 and 1,116.18 are same value but both should pass for the function.
Third: Yes There will be only one numeric value in string (any one of what i mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

If char by char is not a requirement then:

```
def evaluate(string, values):
    for word in string.rstrip('.').split():
        if word in values:
            return False
    return True
```

Test:

```
>>> values = map(str, [14 , 14.98 , 114 , 114.98 , 1116])
['14', '14.98', '114', '114.98', '1116']
>>> string = 'You Score is MX 14.98.'
>>> evaluate(string, values)
False
string = 'You Score is MX 115.' # 115 is not in values
>>> evaluate(string, values)
True
```

Comment: Both of solution didn't worked for me too. As much as i understand the problem Noman wants that a string which contains decimal or comma seprated decimal value is in string. A single char read and finally find weather the number is a valid number or not. I am also not able to find any solution ...

Comment: What is the meaning of "didn't work"? You couldn't reproduce the test case I added or you think the function should work differeently? It would be nice if Norman would write a Test like I wrote showing the expected input/output of the function for specific test values. In his example `var` is neither a string or a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to go char by char then:

```
def evaluate(string, values):
    value = []
    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit() or char in ',.':
            value.append(char)
    value = ''.join(value).strip('.,')
    return int(value in values)
```

Test

```
>>> values = ['14', '14.98', '114', '114.98', '1,116.5']
>>> string = 'You Score is MX 14.98.'
>>> evaluate(string, values)
1
string = 'You Score is MX 115.' # 115 is not in values
>>> evaluate(string, values)
0
```

Comment: You can't reproduce the results in the Test section or is something in the Test section wrong?